How add ‘\u’ to a string and convert it to utf-16 in python?
I’m trying to read an utf-16 text from a GSM module (Sim800 L). It gives me :
0633064406270645 06280647 0647064506af06cc

Rather than :
\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645 \u0628\u0647 \u0647\u0645\u06af\u06cc

I tried many ways to add ‘\u’ to first string or even convert it to bytes , but every time python recognizes them real ascii characters.
For example:
> Str=r’\u’ + Str
Result: \\u633064406270645 06280647 0647064506af06cc

And because of double backslash python doesn’t recognize it as utf-16
I am looking for any method to convert the output of GSM module to Unicode.

If the data that is sent to you is actual text of those numbers as you have shown, then adding \u will not have any effect. You will need to take each four digit number and convert it to its binary representation individually. You can then build a Unicode string from the converted numbers.

re.sub(r"[0-9a-f]{4}", lambda x: chr(int(x[0], 16)), string) => سلام به همگی. Is this the expected output?

Exactly…  thanks alot

How are those Unicode characters supposed to be encoded? How do you know that "06280647" are UTF-16 encoded characters and not actual string of numbers?

It's more likely you need to read the file correctly than it is you need to construct Python string literals from what you are currently reading.

Using a combination of modules

re (replace any hexadecimal quadruplet with a suitable character), and
json (handle surrogate pairs correctly).

Note: added a valid surrogate pair (D83DDE0E) as well as a noncharacter (FFFE) to the hard-coded string, merely for debugging purposes:
import re
import json

def repl_unicode( matchobj):
    mo_int = int( matchobj.group(0), 16)
    return chr( mo_int)

text_16 = '0633064406270645 06280647 0647064506af06cc D83DDE0E FFFE'
pattern = '[0-9A-Za-z]{4}'
text_u8 = json.loads( json.dumps( re.sub( pattern, repl_unicode, text_16)))
print( text_16)
print( text_u8)
print( json.dumps( text_u8, ensure_ascii=True).strip('"'))

Output: .\SO\78628940.py

0633064406270645 06280647 0647064506af06cc D83DDE0E FFFE
سلام به همگی  
\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645 \u0628\u0647 \u0647\u0645\u06af\u06cc \ud83d\ude0e \ufffe



It would be better if you try to convert the hexadecimal string into corresponding bytes followed by UTF-16 decoding.
hexdec_str = "0633064406270645 06280647 0647064506af06cc"

byte_data = bytes.fromhex(hexdec_str.replace(' ', ''))

unicode_str = byte_data .decode('utf-16')

Hope you could obtain readable Unicode string by the above method

That drops the spaces though, which is kind of a problem. If it was the correct behavior, you still wouldn't need the .replace(' ', '') though; bytes.fromhex already ignores embedded spaces.

This should use utf-16be to get correct results.

Did you test your code? It produces '㌆䐆✆䔆⠆䜆䜆䔆꼆찆', which is different from 'سلام به همگی' which is equal to '\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645 \u0628\u0647 \u0647\u0645\u06af\u06cc'.
